# The I18N is abnormal when my rails app in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I write a rails app in my local machine`(OSX 10.6.6,Rails 3.0.1,WEBrick)`,All I18n files work fine.when i push the app to my web server`(Centos5.4,Rails 3.0.1,Phusion Passenger version 3.0.2)` I get a error"`Translation missing: en, username_exist`"

My model code:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username, :on => :create, :message => I18n.t("username_exist")
```

My i18n file(config/locales/en.yml):

```
en:
   username_exist: "username exist"
```

I think the model not found i18n file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `I18n.t` at class scope, as you are doing in the call to `validates_uniqueness_of`, it will be evaluated when the file is loaded. That's probably not what you want, because it means the message will always appear in the default locale, rather than using the locale of the user making each request. It may also be causing the problem you are seeing, if the file is loaded before I18n is configured.

Instead, use a symbol:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username, ..., :message => :username_exist
```

And see the documentation for [`ActiveModel::Errors#generate_message`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-generate_message) to see where to place the translation in the locale file.

In fact, you don't even need to provide the `:message` key if you follow the ActiveModel naming convention:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        [your model name, e.g. user]:
          attributes:
            username:
              taken: "username exists"
```

Comment: I think message is simple and easy to maintain.I try to use ActiveModel naming convention and the problem was solved.But i don't know what's wrong with my way,it's a bug maybe.thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the locale in your application.rb ? Like :

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

Comment: yes.i set `config.i18n.default_locale = :en` in application.rb.

Comment: I'm not sure that this kill would work. Better try something like kill -9 and then restart nginx or even better "/etc/init.d/nginx restart". Are you sure that the server was properly restarted ? If so, ignore this comment